# How to add div dynamicallly with style and ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add following div runtime with this style to other  div

```
<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height:180px;">
                </div>
```

parent div:

```
  <div id="graph" class="tabdiv"></div>
```

I want to add grid div to graph div with given style,how to achive this with jquery or javascript,plz help

Answer (score 2):

In JQuery:

```
$('#graph').append('<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height:180px;"></div>')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var newdiv = $('<div/>', { style: "width: 100%; height:180px;", id: "grid" });
        $("#graph").append(newdiv);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following two ways:

1> Use `.append()` when you want parent as return control

```
$('#graph').append('<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height:180px;"></div>')
```

or

2> Use `.appendTo()` when you want child as return control

```
var childDiv='<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height:180px;"></div>';
childDiv.appendTo($('#graph'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('<div></div>', {class:'tabdiv', id:'graph', text:'Hi'}).appendTo('body')
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dCj4B/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('#graph').append("<div id='grid' style='width: 100%; height:180px;'></div>");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ssilas777/hBpQZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's native JavaScript：

```
var 
    node     = document.getElementById('graph'),
    template = '<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height:180px;"></div>'

    node.innerHTML=template  

    //or you can ...

    node.innerHTML+=template
```

may the answer can help u.